# Combinatorics Question of finding number of ways for choosing correct answer

Tags: combinatorics

In a multiple choice test there are six questions, each have four alternative answers of which only one answer is correct. If a candidate answers all the questions by choosing one answer for each question then number of ways to get exactly four correct answer is

Comment: Any thoughts?  This looks like an entirely standard homework problem..and the numbers are small enough so that it's easy to write out all the cases if all else fails.

Comment: How many ways are there to pick out $4$ of the questions? And how many ways can be answered such that exactly the selected questions are answered correctly?

Comment: @lulu might be helpful to explain basic combinations / permutations rules?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends what you count as "different" enumerations. I will assume that if the same set of questions were wrong, but a different of the three wrong choices in any given wrong answer was selected, that is a different enumeration. Since if I did not, the number of choices in each question would be irrelevant.

If we also take that the answers that were right are fixed or given (otherwise the answer would be a trivial $4^6$ enumeration of all possibilities) then:

There are $3$ ways of choosing the wrong answer, in each of the two wrong answers:

$3^2=9$

And there are $\binom{6}{2}=15$ ways these two wrong answers can be distributed among the six questions.

$15\times9=135$

Answer (score -1):

There are $\binom{6}{4} = 15$ ways to choose $4$ question to answer right, $1^4$ ways to choose right answer for each of them and $3^2$ ways to answer two remaining questions. So there are $\binom{6}{4}\cdot 1^4\cdot 3^2 = 135$ ways to answer exactly $4$ questions right.

Comment: Thanks i am facing difficulty in getting 3^2 term, i was thinking that there is no need for thinking about other 2 as we already counted way of choosing four right, but by neglecting two questions there is still possibility of other to getting correct, it will violate exactly four condition.